# ARM Template deployment returing a value that I dont expect

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I am working on writing some Powershell that I am going to use in Azure DevOPS pipelines.  This is to create an AppServiceplan.  I have included the code below.  I have used this same basic template to deploy a few other things and I have not run into this problem before.

This piece of the code `$appSP = Get-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $rgname` does not return a value, which is expected because this is the first time running it, yet its triggering this piece of code `Write-verbose "AppService Plan '$appServicePlanName' already exists."`

So it seems that even though the Get-AzAppServicePlan appears to be blank, maybe its returning some sort of object that I cant see?

Any ideas?

```
function Assert-AppServicePlan {
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    This function will ensure that specified AppServicePlan exists.

    .DESCRIPTION
    Function will check if specified Azure AppServicePlan exists, and if not - it will be created.
    Will return AppServicePLan object or, in case of error, $null.

    .PARAMETER appServicePlanName
    App Service Plan to be checked or created.

    .PARAMETER rgName
    Resource Group.

    .PARAMETER SKU
    SKU for App Service Plan.  Default is P2V2.

    .EXAMPLE
    Assert-AppServicePlan -appServicePlansName "BARF" -rgName "MyResourceGroup" -SKU "F1" -verbose
#>
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateNotNullorEmpty()][string]$appServicePlanName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateNotNullorEmpty()][string]$rgName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateNotNullorEmpty()][string]$SKU
);

$appSP = Get-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $rgname 


if ($notPresent)
{
    Write-Verbose "App Service Plan '$appServicePlanName' doesn't exist. Creating it."
    try
    {
        $appSP = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName `
        $rgname -TemplateFile .\templates\appserviceplan.json `
        -TemplateParameterFile .\templates\appserviceplan.parameters.json `
        -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-verbose "Error while creating App Service Plan."
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
else
{
    Write-verbose "AppService Plan '$appServicePlanName' already exists."
}

return $appSP
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you define `$notPresent`?

Comment: yeah, that `$notPresent` just pops out of nowhere, but probably just a typo, probably its `$appSP`

Comment: WOW, so obvious when you other people look at it.  I honestly DONT know where that came from.  I cribbed much of this code from one of our previous team members.  I think I put it there as a placeholder and never figured out how to do it.  The goal of course is to check and see if it already exists.  Off to figure that out.  Thanks for the assist.  Sorry it was so obvious

Answer (score 0):

The [Get-AzAppServicePlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azappserviceplan?view=azps-5.6.0) cmdlet returns the App Service Plan object if found in the specified resource group, else nothing. So, it would be sufficient to check on this result in your `if` condition.

Another case where the result might mislead returning null is when you query under an incorrect PS context or a different Subscription (locally). However, since you intend to run this as part of Azure DevOps pipelines, the Service connection used by the task would ensure it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion, you can use `ErrorVariable`

```
Get-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ErrorAction Silentlycontinue -ErrorVariable notPresent

if ($notPresent)
{
   #create something
}
else {
  #exits
}
```